# Make [procmon] a synonym of [process-monitor]?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-request

The tag description for [process-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process-monitor) is:

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity.

while [procmon](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/procmon) is:

> Process Monitor is a free advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity.

The two tags clearly refer to the same topic, i.e. the Windows application `Process Monitor`.
Would it make sense to make procmon a synonym of process-monitor, because procmon was the old name and Process Monitor is the current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Would it make sense to make procmon a synonym of process-monitor?

Yes. I've proposed the synonym. It now needs some [votes to approve](https://superuser.com/tags/process-monitor/synonyms):

> Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms.
>
> Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

I've no idea whether there are enough users with sufficient score to vote and approve ...